# Round of experiance in years months

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I am saving employees work experiance for example as 5.14 n all when I display it, it should show me as 6.2yrs of experiance;

How can I calculate it in PHP or laravel framework?

Comment: 5.14 is string?

Comment: So if the number is 5.14 it should be rounded to 6.2?

Comment: I guess he meant 5 years 14 months get converted into 6 years 2 months, but I could be wrong though

Comment: Could be. But why would anyone write 5 years and 14 months? Sounds like OP is trying to fix something that is not broken

Answer (score 0):

If you mean 6.14 to round up to 6.2.

You can use the the following function of PHP:

```
function round_up($e)
{
    $e = explode(".", $e);
    $e[1] = ceil($e[1] / 10);
    return implode(".", $e);
}
```

With the `ceil()` function you can round up to the next highest integer value. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php).

If you mean 5.14 to round up to 6.2 (as in 14 months). You can use the following function:

```
function round_up($e)
{
    $e = explode(".", $e);
    $e[0] = $e[0] + round($e[1] / 12);
    $e[1] = $e[1]%12;
    return implode(".", $e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you 5.14 as string i have created simple function for you

```
<?php
function totalEexperience($experience) 
{
     $experience = '5.14';
     $array = explode(".",$experience);
     $resultArray[] = $array[0] + round($array[1]/12);
     $resultArray[] = $array[1] % 12;
     $totalExperience = implode(".", $resultArray);    
     return $totalExperience;
}
?>
```